# Omit seconds in NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I'm using this function to return a given NSDate without seconds nor nanoseconds:

```
-(NSDate *)dateByOmittingSeconds:(NSDate *)date
{
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian]; // Setup an NSCalendar
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components: NSUIntegerMax fromDate: date]; // Setup NSDateComponents
[components setSecond:0]; // Set the seconds
[components setNanosecond:0]; // Set the nanoseconds

return [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents: components];
}
```

I'm initializing the `NSCalendar` like so:

```
[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
```

Shoud I use that, or would it be better with this initialization:

```
[NSCalendar currentCalendar];
```

in order to adapt more properly do the different places my app will be used?

Thanks!

Comment: use `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]`

Answer (score 1):

`NSDate` objects represent exact moments in time (regardless of calendar). There is no reason to involve a calendar at all here.

Just use `fmod`:

```
- (NSDate *) dateByOmittingSeconds:(NSDate *) date
{
     NSTimeInterval ti = [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
     ti = ti - fmod(ti, 60.0);
     return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:ti];
}
```

Or alternatively, divide by and re-multiply by 60:

```
- (NSDate *) dateByOmittingSeconds:(NSDate *) date
{
     NSTimeInterval ti = [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
     ti = floor(ti / 60.0) * 60.0;
     return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:ti];
}
```

Comment: After praying that there is no time offset with seconds in it, after praying that in the user's calendar "seconds", "minutes", and "hours" have the same meaning, you still have to pray, that there is no leap second.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: `NSDate` objects have no timezone, are completely agnostic to any calendar, and Cocoa's API does not account for leap seconds anyway.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: Also, `NSTimeInterval` represents NTP seconds.

Comment: Indeed, `NSDate` have no tz. This is the *problem*, because the user's time has a tz. What he will get is possibly no minute in the user's time.

Comment: NTP supports leap seconds.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: NTP supports leap seconds but Cocoa doesn't.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: Once you have an `NSDate` object, it has already lost all timezone information. The input and output to the function in OP's code are both `NSDate` objects, so reintroducing a calendar is unnecessary.

Comment: Cocoa does not support leap seconds for the calculation of time differences.

Comment: Indeed, an `NSDate` object lost all tz information. (No, that's wrong. It does not have one.) This is the *problem*, because the user's time has a tz. What he will get is possibly no minute in the user's time.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: From Apple: **CFCalendar is subject to some limitations. There is no leap second handling—the existence of leap seconds is ignored as in the other CoreFoundation API. In general, historical accuracy of calendars is not guaranteed. There is currently no API for defining your own calendars.**

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement and Apple's documentation, I would go with the second option. `-initWithCalendarIdentifier` will return the calendar you specify, which isn't very dynamic. On the other hand, `+currentCalendar` will return the "logical calendar for the current user" based on their system locale and any custom user settings.

Here's Apple's documentation on the subjects:

> **+currentCalendar**
>
> Returns the logical calendar for the current user.
>
> The returned calendar is formed from the settings for the
>   current user’s chosen system locale overlaid with any custom settings
>   the user has specified in System Preferences. **Settings you get from
>   this calendar do not change as System Preferences are changed, so that
>   your operations are consistent** (contrast with
>   autoupdatingCurrentCalendar).
>
> **-initWithCalendarIdentifier:**
>
> Initializes a newly-allocated NSCalendar object **for the calendar specified by a given identifier**.
>
> The initialized calendar, or nil if the identifier is unknown (if, for example, it is either an unrecognized string or the calendar is not supported by the current version of the operating system).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do with the date. If you simply want to show it to the user (or store it locally) it is better to use the user's setting. You get this with `+currentCalendar`. If you want to share the date around the world (i. e. sending it to a server), it is better to use a uniform calendar for all apps.

Answer (score -1):

My code help you.You can fetch date without second and nano second

```
NSDate *date;
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute  fromDate:date];
```